# Partitioning the array into k non-empty non-intersecting subsegments such that each subsegment has odd sum

Tags: c++, set, subset, subset-sum

I am new in competitive programming. The other day I was solving this problem

You are given an array a consisting of n integers a1,a2,…,an. You want to split it into exactly k non-empty non-intersecting subsegments such that each subsegment has odd sum (i. e. for each subsegment, the sum of all elements that belong to this subsegment is odd). It is impossible to rearrange (shuffle) the elements of a given array. Each of the n elements of the array a must belong to exactly one of the k subsegments.

I  made this following observations:

1.If n lesser than(<) k then it is impossible to get such segments.

2.If k=1 then we already have the segments.

3.If k is odd then in order to get the partitions sum of all entries should be odd and even if k is even.

Based on this I want to frame a logic for partitions. I followed the code given in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-set-k-subsets-equal-sum/ but I think that this code can be shortened with some logic. But I am yet to structure a concrete algorithm.

**Can you guys help me out with an algorithm for doing this task. You can feel free to share any ideas**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by noting that the code you linked is intended to solve a different problem than the one you've outlined--and the fact that it allows rearranging the elements of the array almost certainly makes it a more difficult problem.

For the problem you've outlined, just dividing the array into N sub-arrays, each of which is odd, let's start by looking at the properties of odd and even numbers. Specifically, the sum of even numbers is always even. The sum of an even number of odd numbers is also even. For the sum to be odd, the input must contain an odd number of odd numbers.

Based on that, we can determine whether the desired result is possible fairly easily. To get K partitions, each with an odd sum, the input must contain at least K odd numbers. If not, we can't possibly create K partitions that are odd.

So, if it contains exactly K odd numbers, the answer is immediately "yes", we can do the partition. We can start from the beginning, and stop each partition at the first odd number we encounter. When we've created K-1 partitions that way, the remainder of the input becomes the last partition.

Each of our partitions contains exactly one odd number, and we've partitioned each of the K odd numbers into its own partition, so we've met the requirements.

If there are more than K odd numbers in the input, we have to consider exactly how many more. We want each partition to contain an even sum plus one odd number. That even sum can be produced by any number of even numbers, optionally combined with an even number of odd numbers.

So, let's count the odd numbers in the input, and call that M. If K-M is an even number, then (again) we can pick the K-1 partitions as before--an arbitrary number of even numbers followed by a single odd number. Since each contains only one odd number, those all have odd sums.

The last partition will (again) be a single odd number + a sum of some even numbers + the sum of an even number of odd numbers, so (again) its sum will be odd.

In fact, we can quickly realize that the first case (exactly K odd numbers) is really just a special case of the second, where K-M = 0, and we treat [0, 2, 4, 8, ...] as even numbers.

So you're right: code for this probably can be simpler than for the problem you linked. Start by counting the odd numbers in the input. If it's K+M (where M is an even number), you can create each partition going from the current beginning through the next odd number, and repeating until you get K-1 partitions, then the rest of the input goes in the last partition. If M is an odd number, then the task simply can't be done for this input.

Comment: Thank you. Good approach. Two more inference to add implicitly though you have discussed. i) If m-k<0, not possible ii) If m-k is odd, not possible.